# Python -> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^

Tags: python, algorithm, list, numpy, equation

I am struggling with Python code. I want to do this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w90WN.png).

This my code:

```
fs= 5000
T=np.linspace(0,2.2,fs)
n=np.arange(fs*2.2)
u=[]
for x in T:
    if x < 0.2:
        u.append(x * np.sin(34*np.pi*n/fs))
    if (x >= 0.2 and x < 0.8):
        u.append(1/x * np.log10(x+1))
    if x >= 0.8 and x < 1.4:
        u.append((x^2 + 1) * np.sin(12*np.pi*n/fs))
    if x >= 1.4:
        u.append(np.sin(20*np.pi*n/fs + x/3))
```

And python returns:

```
  File "D:/Semestr V/Podstawy Transmisji Danych/labki-ZAD3.py", line 20, in <module>
    u.append((x^2 + 1) * np.sin(12*np.pi*n/fs))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'numpy.float64' and 'int'
```

Comment: There is no question and the title by itself does not make sense.

Comment: For stylistic purposes, use the if, elif, else convention for your logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258537/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-int)

Comment: for [functional programing fans](https://repl.it/repls/AuthorizedFarflungCaterpillar)

Answer (score 3):

The power operator is `**`, `^` is bitwise XOR.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the mistake `^/**`, the good way is to use [`np.piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) which is intended for that for a quick vectored result:

```
fs= 5000
x=np.linspace(0,2.2,fs)
n=3

functions=[ 
lambda x : x * np.sin(34*np.pi*n/fs), 
lambda x : 1/x * np.log10(x+1),
lambda x : (x**2 + 1) * np.sin(12*np.pi*n/fs),
lambda x : np.sin(20*np.pi*n/fs + x/3)]

conditions=[x < 0.2,(x >= 0.2) & (x < 0.8), (x >= 0.8) & (x < 1.4), x >= 1.4]

res=np.piecewise(x,conditions,functions)
plt.plot(x,res)
```

[image]

just loop on `n` for all the values.