# Calculate a simple expression in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to calculate (π/4)^2-sin⁡(π/4) in python:

```
import math
a=((math.pi)^2/16)-math.sin(math.pi/4)
print(a)
```

It gives the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'
```

I also tried using

```
a=float(((math.pi)^2/16)-math.sin(math.pi/4))
```

But still doesn't work

Comment: Oh. maybe I should use ** instead of ^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python -> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287462/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for)

Answer (score 1):

`^` is not supported in python. Instead, you can use `math.pow`.

```
import math
a=(math.pow((math.pi),2)/16.0)-math.sin(math.pi/4)
print(a)
```

Comment: I used ** but it gives wrong answer! What is the problem of **?

Comment: I used math.pow too it gives the same wrong answer. It gives -0.09025 but in calculator it says 0.6031

Comment: ** is the same as pow for power 2. I tried executing the same code with python(-0.09025650611846259) and calculator(-0.09025650611), I am getting the same response with a value up to 11 digits in the calculator.

Comment: I don't know why my calculator gives this answer

Comment: I realize now. I think it is because I should give the input as degree to the calculator .

Comment: You can clear your memory of your calculator and try again. Or, else use an online calculator. The response shared is from an online calculator.

Answer (score 1):

**^** is not supported in python. Instead, you can use **math.pow** or **

`math.pow(math.pi,2)`

`math.pi ** 2`

Answer (score 0):

No sense in evaluating pi/4 twice.

```
import math
pi4 = math.pi/4
a = pi4**2 - math.sin(pi4)
```