# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math
phi = math.sqrt(5) / 2
pi = (802 * phi - 801) / (602 * phi - 601)
pi = round(pi ^ 4)
print("Pi is equivalent to", pi)
```

I am trying to create a program that calculates the approximate value of pi., However, it returns an error in line 4.

What is wrong here? Both pi and 4 ar either integers or floats so shouldn't exponents be fine?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/run module.py", line 4, in <module>
    pi = round(pi ^ 4)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'
```

Comment: what error? ....

Comment: ^ is the bitwise XOR operator, not the exponent operator. Thatll be **

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258537/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-int)

Comment: This is pretty irrelevant but math has a function called `math.pi` you can use. It returns `3.141592653589793`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the exponentiation (i.e., power) operator in Python. You want `**` instead of `^`.

```
import math
phi = math.sqrt(5) / 2
pi = (802 * phi - 801) / (602 * phi - 601)
pi = round(pi ** 4)
print("Pi is equivalent to", pi)
```

Granted, this won't give a great result. It'll just give you `3` because of the `round` call.

If you want something slightly better, remove the rounding. Change that error line to:

```
pi = pi ** 4
```

Now you'll get `3.1066259768762885`. Not perfect, but certainly better.

Of course, another fun way to approximate pi comes [from Randall Munroe](https://xkcd.com/687/).

### Fixing the math; improving the approximation

But you want something exact to 7 decimal places, and [your approximation should be](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiApproximations.html).

> Another approximation involving the golden ratio phi is given by
> pi approx ((802phi-801)/(602phi-601))^4,
> (18)
> which is good to 7 digits (K. Rashid, pers. comm.).

The issue is that your definition of `phi` is incorrect. Try `phi = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2`.

```
import math
phi = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2  # Correct definition for golden ratio
pi = (802 * phi - 801) / (602 * phi - 601)
pi = round(pi ** 4, 7)
print("Pi is equivalent to", pi)
```

You'll get `3.1415926`, as was sought.

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried to round it to 7 decimal places instead pi = round(pi ** 4, 7) but it isn't giving me the expected pi value, is there something wrong with that?

Comment: Yes, there's a mistake in your math. I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import math
phi = math.sqrt(5) / 2
pi = (802 * phi - 801) / (602 * phi - 601)
pi = round(pi ** 4) #CHANGES MADE HERE
print("Pi is equivalent to", pi)
```

Should make it work because you had used '^' or the Bitwise Operator. For exponents, use '**'.